# find_package() on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

Tags: ros, catkin, path, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry in advance if this is a poorly constructed idea/question.

I have strict orders that I can't use `caktin build` and that I should only use basic make/cmake commands to control the build process.

I am building a package of messages and then trying to `find_package()` that message package from another package that needs to use them. I provide the config files below for the message package `amrl_msgs`. If there is a fundamentally better way to try to do what I want to do, I am eager to hear, as long as it doesn't involve using `catkin build/make` :)

When I try to `find_package(amrl_msgs)` in another project I get a

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "amrl_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    amrl_msgsConfig.cmake
    amrl_msgs-config.cmake
```

error, even though the `amrl_msgsConfig.cmake` is found in `amrl_msgs/build/devel/share/amrl_msgs/cmake` and I have both the of the packages on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. I am assuming the way to solve this problem is not with the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, but I also don't want to have to hardcode the absolute path to  `amrl_msgsConfig.cmake` every time I use it. How do I direct the system to be able to find the messages without hardcoding the path?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(amrl_msgs)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  std_msgs
  message_generation
) 

add_message_files(
  FILES
  Point2D.msg
  ColoredArc2D.msg
  ColoredLine2D.msg
  ColoredPoint2D.msg
  Localization2DMsg.msg
  PathVisualization.msg
  Point2D.msg
  Pose2Df.msg
  RobofleetStatus.msg
  RobofleetSubscription.msg
  VisualizationMsg.msg
 )

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
 )

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS build/devel/include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS std_msgs message_runtime
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370868/find_package()-on-ros_package_path?/) by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 977 on 2021-02-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-02**:\

> am assuming the way to solve this problem is not with the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` [..]

afaik CMake does not look at that variable for locations where it should look for `*Config.cmake` files.

You'll probably want/need to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, which is one of the jobs Catkin (the tool) takes care of for you.

There is no magic, it's all just CMake.

---

Edit:

> ```
> INCLUDE_DIRS build/devel/include
> ```

are you sure this is correct? Afaik paths passed to `INCLUDE_DIRS` should be relative to the `CMakeLists.txt` / package root. You appear to be referring to a directory generated during the build. And pure message packages typically don't export any include directories. That gets taken care of by `generate_messages(..)` and `message_runtime` et al.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-02**:\

> I also don't want to have to hardcode the absolute path to `amrl_msgsConfig.cmake` every time I use it

CMake will crawl the FS to some extent, but unfortunately if you're not using Catkin, you're now responsible for updating the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` such that it contains the locations CMake should crawl to look for `*Config.cmake` files.

That's again CMake, not Catkin.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-02**:
Perhaps the [catkin/what: Structured Atomic Workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/what#Structured_Atomic_Workspaces) section helps.

**Comment by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) on 2021-02-02**:
using the following command " catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps <target_package> " you can build the specific  package instead of building all the packages in your system. Also if you have the package path you can put it in bashrc file so it will be loaded at all the times. you also can make a new enviorment and build your package there and source it into the bashrc file this will requires catkin_make however since it is in diffrent enviorment it will not make any issue for your current packages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-03**:
@AmirSaman: the OP stated he cannot/is not allowed to use Catkin (the tool) in any way.

It's not clear to me how your comment addresses the issue and takes that into account.

**Comment by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) on 2021-02-03**:
@gvdhoorn I am just suggesting those ways in case if OP not aware of it which could enable him to do the catkin_make and solve his problem else what you have suggested earlier could help to settle this issue.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2021-02-03**:
Thanks for the feedback guys! That reading on Atomic Workspaces was very helpful to put the problem into context. I think there is not a good way to do what I want without hard coding paths in the CMake, or using `make install` to put the config files in more friendly locations (which isn't useful because often this will require sudo privileges). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure I understand why you need to "hard code paths in the CMake".

`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is an environment variable. As long as the `*Config.cmake` files are in the appropriate location, CMake will find them.

Note: it's a *prefix* path, not a full path. CMake searches a few standard locations in each path on the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2021-02-04**:
You are 100% right! That is honestly exactly the solution I was looking for. We can just add the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH of each package to the .bashrc or export it in each terminal session. Thanks so much!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-04**:
Yes, as I explained before: that's what Catkin does for you (among other things).